# How to solve dropdown menu problem

Tags: dropdown

Please look and help me how to solve this

I want look like:
[Here](http://s22.postimg.org/mk0d7u5e9/image.png)

But my code show:

[On Chrome](http://s4.postimg.org/sj36cml9p/image.png)
[On mozilla](http://s21.postimg.org/5uv90xhaf/mozilla.png)

Website link [Here](http://markcdm.tk/1)

Comment: Perhaps you should read [how to ask a good question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the dropdown symbol a webfont? becuase it is not getting loaded. There's a 404 error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Yes, may be. How can i solve this problem?